# simple html5 way to vertically split a website page in vertical slides with navigation

Tags: html, css

Do you know a way to split a webpage in simple vertical-sliding slides using html5 section tags, anchors, css and js ?

If I just put the `section` tags, the sections do not occupy the full height of the page and the user can several section on the same viewport.

I would like each section to be full width and full height in the client browser, whatever his screen size.

Thanks

Comment: what can I do to avoid vote down ? This question is legitimate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use links to take you to the relevant sections, e.g.:

```
<a  href="#slide1">Slide 1</a>
<a  href="#slide2">Slide 2</a>
<a  href="#slide3">Slide 3</a>

<section id="slide1" class="slide">
    <h1>section 1</h1>
    <p>This is a section</p>
</section>

<section id="slide2" class="slide">
    <h1>section 2</h1>
    <p>This is a section</p>
</section>

<section id="slide3" class="slide">
    <h1>section 3</h1>
    <p>This is a section</p>
</section>
```

With css :

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
}

section{
    margin-bottom:400px;
}
```

To get a smooth scroll you can use this jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**DEMO**:http://jsfiddle.net/vA9ga/4/

Comment: nice @tomsullivan ! I was editing my question when you were answering : can you also make each `section` full height, so the user only sees the current section ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok I found the solution and put it this version of your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vA9ga/2/

Comment: See my answer, I've updated the jsFiddle. Is this what you're after?

Comment: I've changed it again now so that the height is always 100% of the screen.

Comment: How come you don't just use width=100% ? is there a disadvantage of doing this ?

Comment: And @tomsullivan1989, can you make it so the user can't stay astride on two slides.... I mean so that when he starts scrolling down even a little, it goes automatically and fully to the next slide ?

Comment: Width=100% is the default width. I haven't got the time at the moment to implement that automatic scrolling. You will need some JavaScript to do this, good luck!